# CEILING returns FLOOR result - SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, floor, ceil

```
DECLARE @a int;
DECLARE @b int;

SET @a = 9;
SET @b = 2;

SELECT CEILING (@a/@b);
```

It is returning as 4 instead of 5. Why?

**Edit:** I would like to get next smallest integer if the quotient is not whole number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT CEILING (@a/CAST(@b AS float))
```

And consider `NULLIF(@b,0)` too, to avoid a Division By Zero error.

Answer (score 4):

After dividing 9 by 2 a decimal fraction is *Truncated* to its integer part - 4, not *Rounded* to 5. Try:

```
SELECT 9/2
```

Resilt is 4. Then `CEILING(4) = 4`

To get next integer declare variables as data types that can handle decimal part: `NUMERIC`,`FLOAT`, `REAL`.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server does integer division.  So 9/2 = 4 in SQL Server.

Taking the ceiling of an integer is the same integer.

Comment: Ok, but my inputs for Stored Procedure are Integers :( then how do I get 5?